# Using a RouteCollectionProvider in Silex

Tags: php, events, silex, dispatch

I have a custom `Silex\RouteCollection` which I want to register...

```
class RouteCollectionProvider extends RouteCollection
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->add(
            'Index',
            new Route('/', array(
                'method' => 'get',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

...during the bootstrapping:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
/**  here  **/
$app->run();
```

I could use:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$routes = new RouteCollectionProvider();
foreach ($routes->getIterator() as $route) {
     $defaults = $route->getDefaults();
     $pattern  = $route->getPath();
     $callback = 'Controller\\'
         . ucfirst($defaults['controller'])
         . 'Controller::'
         . $defaults['action']
         . 'Action';
     $app->get($pattern, $callback);
}
$app->run();
```

I don't like having the initialization of those routes right in there.
Do you know any spot in Silex, where this does fit better?

I cannot use `$app->register()` because it's getting called too late and the routes won't get *active* in there.

Maybe there is an event I can use with

```
$app->on('beforeCompileRoutesOrSomething', function() use ($app) {
    // initialize routes
}
```

Or a hook in the Dispatcher?

My aim is to not have a big collection of `$app->get()` or `$app->post()` in there. I also know I can `->mount()` a `controller` but then still I have all my `get` definitions in my bootstrap and not in a Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post solves the problem: [Scaling Silex pt. 2](http://gonzalo123.com/2013/03/04/scaling-silex-applications-part-ii-using-routecollection/).

```
$app = new Application;

$app->extend('routes', function (RouteCollection $routes, Application $app) {
    $routes->addCollection(new MyCustomRouteCollection);
     return $routes;
});

$app->run();
```